# Nokia Android SDK is not working

Tags: android, here-api, nokiax

I am trying to embed turn by turn navigation into my android mobile application. I have found that Nokia has an android api. I have followed https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/app-simple.html to embedd the nokia here maps into my android application.

The problem is when I open the application, the screen is blank and map dosent load. I tried to debug and found that OnEngineInitListener() of mapFragment is generating and error "UNKNOWN"

```
// Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
    mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapfragment);
    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                        OnEngineInitListener.Error error)
        {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                                Map.Animation.NONE);
                // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                map.setZoomLevel(
                    (map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
    });
```

Has anyone worked with Nokia HERE Android API ? If yes and you have face a similar problem, kindly share your solution.

I would really appreciate it if some one could suggest me a maps api that provides turn by turn navigation which I can embed into my android application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the evaluation or productive version of HERE Android SDK? What is the version number? What is the evaluation date?
You can find all that information from the zip file name which contains the SDK.

Comment: This should be a comment to the question. No real answer here.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough points to add comments to other people posts. :)